# [Azure][Application Insights agent for Java]java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: http/RequestLine

Tags: java, azure, agent

After launch my jetty with applicationinsights-agent-1.0.6.jar as agent (See https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-java-agent.md), I get following stack trace. Remove the agent remove the stack trace.

I don't understand why it bother with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: http/RequestLine", I found this class nowhere ...

Is someone has the same issue?

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: http/RequestLine
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:1231)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.ApacheSender43.<init>(ApacheSender43.java:52)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.ApacheSenderFactory.create(ApacheSenderFactory.java:40)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.TransmissionNetworkOutput.<init>(TransmissionNetworkOutput.java:95)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.TransmissionNetworkOutput.create(TransmissionNetworkOutput.java:85)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannelFactory.create(InProcessTelemetryChannelFactory.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannel.initialize(InProcessTelemetryChannel.java:263)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannel.<init>(InProcessTelemetryChannel.java:147)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.setChannel(TelemetryConfigurationFactory.java:396)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.initialize(TelemetryConfigurationFactory.java:102)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration.getActive(TelemetryConfiguration.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient.<init>(TelemetryClient.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.common.LogTelemetryClientProxy.<init>(LogTelemetryClientProxy.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender.activateOptions(ApplicationInsightsAppender.java:103)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.doOnChange(DOMConfigurator.java:1125)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.java:89)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.<init>(FileWatchdog.java:58)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.<init>(DOMConfigurator.java:1117)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurator.java:718)
```

Command line

```
    java -Djetty.home=/opt/servers/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/servers/jetty-base  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -javaagent:/opt/servers/jetty-base/lib/ext/applicationinsights-agent-1.0.6.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp /opt/servers/jetty/start.jar org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main &
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception [`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html), it means some dependent libraries like `httpclient` were missed in the command line.

As to resolve it, you need to download the [zip file](https://aijavasdk.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/sdk.zip) of Application Insights SDK for Java from the [page](https://aijavasdk.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/sdk.html), and append them with the `:`  delimiter to the tail of the option `-cp`.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes, I understand than NoClassDefFoundError means that the class is unavailable. But what is the "http/RequestLine" class? Where did it comes? Without the agent, program is ok, with the agent it complains missing class...

Comment: It comes from `org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore`, please see the links [1](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/RequestLine.html) & [2](http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.1/org.apache.http.RequestLine).

Comment: Yes I found "org.apache.http.RequestLine" but the error is about "http.RequestLine"